# Change speed during animation CSS3 + Keyframes or transitions

Tags: css-transitions, css-animations

I want to spin a square at a fixed speed, and then, at some point during animation, I want to speed it up.

This is my attempt:

http://codepen.io/JAStanton/pen/uzfji

so far but in Safari it flickers. Other ideas are animating with pure JavaScript, though this has some perf costs on mobile.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by chaining 2 animations:

```
-webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear 0s, mymove2 2s linear 4s;
```

The second one will run after 4 seconds of delay so you don't have to listen for events.
Additionally you could achieve this effect trough the easing function by using a custom Bezier

Is this what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtYCW/

Comment: the problem with that is that i don't know the duration of the first animation. and I don't know the speed of the next animation either. Not until I need to change it.